# How do I debug docker port mapping?

Tags: docker, port

I'm stuck with getting port mapping to work with a docker instance I've built. `curl localhost` in the docker container shows the application is working fine, but curl from host returns:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: 127.0.0.1/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I've exposed the port with `-p` flag. I've tried mapping all sorts of different ports.
How might I debug this? What are common problems with port mapping?

Comment: Make sure the image exposes the 8080 port :) Because I was doing -p 8000:8000 all the time. Took long to do ****:8080

Comment: i had a similar issue. it was working in production with nginx where i set a custom `PORT_PROD` value in the .env file, but when i tried to rename it to `PORT_DEV` in development, it stopped working, so renaming it back to `PORT` solved it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're doing `curl` outside of the container - it won't work. If I understand you correctly then you have several variants:

1. Use command `docker inspect --format='{{range $p, $conf := .NetworkSettings.Ports}} {{$p}} -> {{(index $conf 0).HostPort}} {{end}}' $INSTANCE_ID` - more on [Docker Inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/).
2. Use command `docker port $CONTAINER_NAME` - more on [Docker Port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/).

Execute command `docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' <CONTAINER_NAME>`. It should show you internal IP-address and then try to `curl <IP_FROM_COMMAND>:<PORT>`.

Comment: Hey, I've tried `docker port` 8000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8000, still, using curl localhost:8000 doesn't seem to work. Is there something else I can try to debug?

Comment: Interesting, I got the address and tried with that ie (`curl 172.17.0.2:8000`) and got `Connection refused`. I tried the same from inside the container and it gave the same thing. Perhaps docker is working but the container is not accepting connections aside from localhost/127.0.0.1 ? ... thanks yuri.

Comment: @digitalWestie don't mention it :) Try to use simple [nginx container](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) and see what you will get :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Yuri you can simply use command:

```
docker ps
```

It shows you table info about containers:

`CONTAINER ID`, `IMAGE`, `COMMAND`, `CREATED`, `STATUS`, `PORTS`, `NAMES`

Then you know `<CONTAINER_ID>` for such commands as

```
docker port <CONTAINER_ID>
docker inspect <CONTAINER_ID>
```